# Join three (3) MySQL tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join

unfortunately i'm not that good as SQL and i'm trying to get a join between three tables done.

here's a rough simplified table structure:

```
links: id, url, description
categories: id, name, path
link_cat: link_id, cat_id
```

The select statement I'm aiming for should have

```
links.id, link.url, link.description, categories.name, categories.path
```

Where links and categories are matched via the link_cat table. I think that shouldn't be too hard as long as there's only one category for each link. This is what I'm assuming. If not it would be good to have another way that pulls multiple categories comma separated into the categories.name field.

I hope this is all understandable and doesn't sound too silly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT links.id, links.url, links.description, categories.name, categories.path
FROM links
INNER JOIN link_cat ON links.id = link_cat.links_id
INNER JOIN categories ON categories.id = link_cat.category_id
```

Comment: beat me to it by 10 seconds! :)

Comment: that's it. Thanks for your input. I already worked that out myself after the Answer from Parris a bit below wasn't quite right but yours hit the nail.

Comment: You should remove the cartesian join from this by taking the first instance of `categories` and `link_cat` out of the FROM clause.

Answer (score 1):

```
# Add each field you want to the select list
SELECT links.id, link.url, link.description, categories.name, categories.path

# Add the "links" table to the list of tables to select from
FROM links

# Add the "link_cat" table, specify "link_id" as the common field
JOIN link_cat USING (link_id)

# Add the "categories" table specifying the "cat_id" as the common field
JOIN categories USING (cat_id)
```

Comment: Thanks, You input gave some good hints but didn't work quite well. I though used it to google a bit and found it out. Though Filipe a few posts after nailed it right.

Comment: I'm happy you got an answer that works, but I'm not sure Filipe's answer below is what you're looking for.  Even if it didn't throw an error for duplicate table aliases, it has redundant cartesian joins in it.

Answer (score 1):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6a81e/1

```
SELECT 
  l.id, 
  l.url, 
  l.description,
  c.name,
  c.path
FROM links l
INNER JOIN link_cat lc
ON lc.link_id = l.id
INNER JOIN categories c
ON lc.cat_id = c.id
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT links.id, links.url, links.description, categories.name, categories.path
FROM links
INNER JOIN link_cat     ON link_cat.link_id = links.id
INNER JOIN categories   ON link_cat.cat_id  = categories.id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT link.id, link.url, link.description, categories.name, categories.path
FROM link, categories, link_cat
WHERE
    link.id = link_cat.link_id
    AND categories.id = link_cat.category_id
```

Comment: ANSI-89 style should be avoided nowadays in place of ANSI-92.  (https://36chambers.wordpress.com/2014/02/18/t-sql-anti-patterns-ansi-89-joins/)

Comment: your example works but misses the link_cat table in FROM. With that inserted in it works. Thanks.

Comment: @Helmi right, updated my answer. However I agree with Parris that Filipe's syntax is preferable.